# Execute php locally and pass $_POST

Tags: php

I have a php script on a web server that's called over the internet and then accesses the $_POST array to retrieve the passed data. Beside calling this script from the web page (`<form action="form.php" method="post">`) I'm also able to call it from a local bash script running on the server:

```
postData='form_name=Georg&form_email=george%40example.com&form_message=Something%20new&id_button=true'
curl -X POST -d $postData https://example.com/form.php
```

Now I want to get rid of curl and call the script directly with the data I have prepared, like:

```
php /var/www/example/form.php -- $postData
```

How do I prepare and pass the $postData correctly, such that I don't have to change the script and can access the passed data, like $_POST['form_email'], as though called over the internet?

Comment: From memory if you want to retrieve data passed as parameters to a PHP script launched on the command line you will have to use the "argv" array. So you will have to modify your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not without modifying your code that is; `$_POST` is automatically populated by PHP. Without changing too much code what you can do is add the following to the top of `form.php`:

```
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    parse_str($argv[1], $_POST);
}
```

For the remainder of your script you should be able to use `$_POST` as if it was called via web.

Comment: Yes, works. But I had to eliminate the `--` from my sample command line